# How to install CRUD bundle with Symfony std. vendors 2.2 and Windows using NetBeans

Tags: symfony, netbeans, installation, bundle, symfony-2.2

I would like to install bundle:
http://knpbundles.com/sachoo/CrudGen

I use:
NetBeans 7.3 with successfully configured Symfony standard vendors 2.2
Windows 8
Wamp Server 2.2

can anyone please guide me how to install that bundle step by step as I am complete beginner in that topic and don't understand examples provided at web, perhaps lot of them is for 2.1 or 2.0 version of Symfony that differs form latest release 2.2.

I tried to find any command related to that topic in NetBeans>Symfony>Run command but have not found any to do that.
Shall I modify some Symfony files by hand?

Comment: You should read this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html

Comment: I cleared the root composer.json file and put into it content of that: https://github.com/sachoo/CrudGen/blob/master/composer.json but when I run composer install command i get info from composer: Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.jso
n. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files, Even when I do update before install composer does not install a bundle. What is going on?

Comment: Surely you have a `composer.json` in your project, just add `"sachoo/crudgen-bundle": "dev-master"` in your `require` list and run `php composer.phar update`, then add the bundle object to your `AppKernel`. You don't need to run `php composer.phar install` at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who are new to the topic as me here is a fantastic step by step installation process tutorial:
[Install Symfony 2 development environment on windows](http://0hlsson.se/2012/10/20/install-symfony-2-development-environment-on-windows-part-1-installing-git/) follow it and then
don't delete content of your composer.json file that is placed in root directory of your project - it is needed to define versions of bundles and dependencies for all already installed components that you could update in future. 
Just add at the list of require:
"sachoo/crudgen-bundle": "dev-master"
note that all item lines on that list are ended by comma "," but not the last one. Example of composer.json require part that works:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "sachoo/crudgen-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

run command in cmd.exe window:

```
composer update sachoo/crudgen-bundle
```

for installing sachoo/crudgen-bundle or

```
composer update
```

for updating all bundles and installing missing one in that case "sachoo/crudgen-bundle"